# What is the best possible way to read the data from a file using readFile and converting it to a List in groovy?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to read values from text files and putting the values into the list using the below method.

```
def myKeys = []
new File( '/tmp/A.txt' ).eachLine { line ->
    myKeys << line
}

def myValues = []
new File( '/tmp/B.txt' ).eachLine { line ->
    myValues << line
}
```

Problem is, Jenkins doesn't allow this to run on a slave and I'm not sure how to use `readFile` method here because it doesn't solve the purpose. I want to create a List, which `readFile` couldn't do.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the same result using `readFile` step. It reads a given file from your workspace and returns the content of the file as a string. Then you can use [`String.eachLine(closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.0/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#eachLine(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method to iterate every line and add it to the list you expect. Keep in mind one thing, however - if you want to use `String.eachLine()` method, you need to do it in the `@NonCPS` mode. Otherwise, you will get maybe a single element from the iteration at best.

Take a look at the following example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Read test.txt file") {
            steps {
                script {
                    final String content = readFile(file: "test.txt")
                    final List myKeys = extractLines(content)
                    echo "myKeys = ${myKeys}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
List extractLines(final String content) {
    List myKeys = []
    content.eachLine { line -> 
        myKeys << line
    }
    return myKeys
}
```

In this example, we use simple `test.text` file with the following content:

```
$ cat test.txt 
123
qwe
asd
zxc
```

Running this exemplary pipeline produces the following output:

```
Running on Jenkins in /home/wololock/.jenkins/workspace/jobA
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Read test.txt file)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
myKeys = [123, qwe, asd, zxc]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

You could use a similar approach to extract keys and values from two different files, e.g.

```
def myKeys = extractLines(readFile(file:"/tmp/A.txt"))
def myValues = extractLines(readFile(file:"/tmp/B.txt"))
```

Comment: Do we need to `close` something after `readFile`, or is that automatically handled for us? I'm surprised this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere...

Comment: final String body = readFile(file: "/tmp/output.text") ..... is giving java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/output.text ......